# Can you recommend me a book that covers optimization of arrays based operations?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, optimization

Can you recommend me a book or a resource that covers optimization techniques for array based operations (loops with inner loops etc.)? (in C# would be great!)

Comment: Keep in mind the compiler already does some of this kind of optimization for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This book looks to be just what you are looking for:

[http://www.amazon.com/Numerical-Methods-Algorithms-Tools-C/dp/0849374790](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0849374790)

Before you purchase a book, however, I would review these links, since they offer a wealth of knowledge:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/algorithm

http://www.dotnetperls.com/optimization